# Why is the sample mean normal when sampling from a normal population

Tags: self-study, mean

I've recently come accross the following statement in Johnson's *Statistics Principles and Methods 9th Edition*

> $\overline{X}$, the sample mean, is normal when sampling from a normal population.

My straightforward - and perhaps naïve - question is: why?

Comment: Because the sum of normals is normal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are bivariate normal their sum is normal (this can be shown in several ways).

In particular for our present purpose, if they're independent and $\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2),\,i=1,2$ respectively then $X_1+X_2\sim N(\sum_i \mu_i,\sum_i \sigma^2_i)$ and hence their mean is as well (since if $Y$ is normal so is $cY$).

Wikipedia gives three proofs for the independence case here: [Sum of normally distributed random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables). It then gives a proof for bivariate normal variables.

Despite the potential implication of the title of the Wikipedia article I linked, it only discusses jointly normal variables. More generally it's not true of sums of normal random variates - if you don't have joint normality it's usually not the case the the sum is normal.

While I've focused on two variables, this discussion applies in turn to $n$ independent variables.

Comment: can you clarify joint normality?

Comment: Variables are jointly normal if they come from a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). Two variables are jointly normal if they come from a bivariate normal distribution. *Independent* normals are always jointly normal. It's (easily) possible to have normal variables which are not jointly normal. (Note that uncorrelated variables are not necessarily independent, even if they're each normal.)

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not well formed. "A" sample mean isn't normal or not normal, it just is -- it can't be 'distributed' because a sample mean is just one number.

I can't be sure without more context but I think the author is referring to the *central limit theorem* which states that the sampling distribution of the mean tends towards normality as sample size increases. And, this is true for [nearly] *any* parent distribution. For instance, if you sample values from an exponential distribution, calculate the mean, then repeat this process, the distribution of those mean values will be normal.

As to the *why* this must be the case, there are mathematical explanations and conceptual ones. Many, actually. One conceptual way to think about it is that a single sample mean 'tries' to do the same thing every time - summarize the parent. Sometimes, you'll sample some extreme values, causing that single mean to vary a bit. But after a series of sample means, the 'errors' you make are equally likely to be above and below the true parent mean, and most likely to be close to the real value. Thus, the distribution is normal.

Comment: No the statement applies to the sampling distribution of sample means in small samples. It has nothing to do with the central limit theorem.

Comment: That wasn't clear from the excerpt!